# Get provisioned access on testflightapp.com for my device

Tags: iphone, testflight

Someone just invited me into their project as a "Developer" (testflightapp.com). I want to be able to test the App. Do I need to wait for the person who is created the builds to add my device to the provisioned list? (Even though I  have developer access?) Is that because they have their unique team id (bundle seed id) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add your device's UDID to the [Apple Developer Portal](http://developer.apple.com).  So, the answer to your question depends on whether you have access to that.

[Testflight FAQ:](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/402851-testflight-faq)

> *[snip]* Invite and gather the
>   UDIDs from the team members and add them to your Apple Developer
>   Portal and provisioning profile for the app. Build the IPhone
>   Application (.IPA) and upload to TestFlight. Distribute the build to
>   team members and let the magic happen. *[snip]*

Answer (score 0):

When you register as a developer on TestFlight, and perform the required actions on your device, it sends your device's UDID to the Team Leader on the TestFlight account.  They will then have to add your UDID through their provisioning profile and create a new build of their app using that updated provisioning profile which includes your device.  Once that new build is submitted to TestFlight, you should get an email to notify you that a new build is available, which you can then download.

Fortunately, once your UDID is added, everything should run smoothly, and you will just be notified when new builds are available.

Comment: You don't have to create a new build, just upload the new provisioning profile to testflight.